# How to add an action to a Row in Android for Cars Android Auto?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

I wanted to show a list in the Car app Android for Android Auto. The list should contain items with two buttons for separate actions.

I tried adding the [addAction()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/model/Row.Builder#addAction(androidx.car.app.model.Action)), but it doesn't seem to be available in Row Class. Could someone help me build a Row or a list item with two buttons, so that I can add it to the ItemList.Builder?

My current code is

```
ListTemplate.Builder templateBuilder = new ListTemplate.Builder();
        ItemList.Builder itemList = new ItemList.Builder();
        templateBuilder.setLoading(isLoading);
        if(!isLoading) {
            for (ParkingList parkingList : parkingList) {
                Row rowItem = new Row.Builder()
                        .setTitle(parkingList.getNome())
                        .setImage(new CarIcon.Builder(
                                        IconCompat.createWithResource(
                                                getCarContext(),
                                                R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                                        .build(),
                                Row.IMAGE_TYPE_LARGE)
                        .setBrowsable(false)
                        .addText(parkingList.getDescrizione())
                        .addText(parkingList.getLat() + " " + parkingList.getLng())
                        .setOnClickListener(
                                () ->
                                        getScreenManager()
                                                .push(new NextScreen(getCarContext())))
                        .build();

                itemList.addItem(rowItem);
            }
            ItemList templateList = itemList.build();
            templateBuilder.setSingleList(templateList); 
        }
        return templateBuilder.setTitle("Parking List").build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
   @Override
        public Template onGetTemplate() {



            ListTemplate.Builder templateBuilder = new ListTemplate.Builder();
            ItemList.Builder itemListBuilder = new ItemList.Builder();
            ItemList itemList = itemListBuilder
            .setOnSelectedListener(this::onSelected).build();
                        
            templateBuilder.addSectionedList(SectionedItemList.create(itemList, "some section header title"));
    
            return templateBuilder.setTitle("MY TITLE").setHeaderAction(BACK).build();
}
```

then you add this:

```
  private void onSelected(int selectedIndex) {


   }
```

hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In a row, the use of addAction() is allowed, but attempting to include more than one action will result in an exception: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Action list exceeded max number of 1 actions." It is also advisable to avoid performing two distinct actions within a single row. If the need arises for dual actions, it is recommended to use a toggle instead. This allows the execution of two actions based on the state of the toggle.

```
Row.Builder()
        .setImage(rowIcon)
        .setToggle(Toggle.Builder {
            if (it) {
                println("On")
            } else {
                println("Off")
            }
        }
            .setChecked(false)
            .build())
        .setTitle(title)
        .build()
}
```